# python regex for filename

Tags: python

I am trying to do a regex on a dataframe.

For example a value will be `ia wt template - tdct-c15-c5.doc`
The best logic I can think of is to take everything after the `-`  till the last digit in the string.

trying to trim it to `tdct-c15-c5`

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `(?<=- )[^ ]+(?=\.doc)`

Comment: If this example has the same structure as any other value that you need to trim, I would recommend you that just split by whitespaces the value and get the last position. Otherwise a regex I am not sure how it could help you unless you give more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Components

To stay flexible, assume your input filename(s) contain chunks:

1. filenames with fix *extension* `.doc` (denoting Word files or documents)
2. some important *key* (here `tdct-c15-c5`)
3. the *separator* as hyphen possibly surrounded by spaces  (here surrounded by spaces `-`)
4. some prefix, does not matter currently (here `ia wt template`)

This information is contained inside `ia wt template - tdct-c15-c5.doc`.

#### Decomposition steps

Particularly the chunks (1) and (3) seem pretty stable and fixed constants.
So lets work with them:

1. we can strip-off from right or remove the *extension* (1) as ignored
2. we can split the remaining basename by *separator* (3) into 2 parts: *prefix* (4) and  *key* (2)

The last part (2) is what we want to extract.

#### Implementation (pure Python only)

```py
def extract_key(filename):
    basename = filename.rstrip('.doc')
    (prefix, key) = basename.split(' - ')  # or use lenient regex r'\ ?-\ ?'
    return key


filename = 'ia wt template - tdct-c15-c5.doc'
print('extracted key:', extract_key(filename))
```

Prints:

`('extracted key:', 'tdct-c15-c5')`

#### Applied to pandas

Use the function as [suggested by C.Nivis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70978268/5730279) inside [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
df.apply(extract_key)
```

Comment: Thanks, say I have a dataframe like : `df.filename` , how do I loop through each row with your function? and store into a new column?

Comment: @Jonnyboi, this assumptive dataframe `df.filename` and the question how to add a new column based on the extracted _key_ is not part of your question. Please also  research as instructed in [ask], e.g. [search SO for `[pandas] new column based on other column`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D%20new%20column%20based%20on%20other%20column)
Would you like to add it there first?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a regex is the better option here. An `apply` is pretty readable:

```py
mystr = "ia wt template - tdct-c15-c5.doc"
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[mystr] for i in range(4)], columns=['mystr'])

df.mystr.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[-1].rstrip('.doc'))
0    tdct-c15-c5
1    tdct-c15-c5
2    tdct-c15-c5
3    tdct-c15-c5
Name: mystr, dtype: object
```